# Error Loading QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

**Couldn't load plugin 'processing'**

Every time I load QGIS 3.4 I get the below error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6/sqlite3/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/D/SQLite3   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6/sqlite3/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-darwin.so   Reason: image not found 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 309, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 39, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 58, in 
    from processing.algs.qgis.QgisAlgorithmProvider import QgisAlgorithmProvider  # NOQA
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/QgisAlgorithmProvider.py", line 84, in 
    from .ImportIntoSpatialite import ImportIntoSpatialite
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/ImportIntoSpatialite.py", line 42, in 
    from processing.tools import spatialite
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/spatialite.py", line 29, in 
    import sqlite3 as sqlite
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from sqlite3._sqlite3 import *
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6/sqlite3/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/D/SQLite3
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6/sqlite3/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found


Python version: 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:04:31) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.5-Madeira Madeira, exported 

Python Path:
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/ABC/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/ABC/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/ABC/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE, could you please provide a little more context information on the circumstances the error occurs under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved this by reinstalling GDAL from the source. After that I never got this error.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue creating the `D` folder in ⁨`/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/`

Then, I have pasted in this folder the `SQLite3` file taken from `/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/` folder